# Sort of 'multicolumn' for align environment

Tags: align, multicolumn

I have something like this:

```
\begin{align}
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i\\
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i\\
 %%%%%
 a+h+q &= b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t\\
       &\quad +u+x+y+w+z
 %%%%%
 \\
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i \\
 \end{align}
```

I am trying to align the third equation with each others at the first 'column' and to span it throught consecutive `&` as I do with `\multicolumn` in a `tabular` environment.

## Some attempts

### One

I have tried with `tabular` and `multicolumn`:

```
\begin{align}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i\\
    \multicolumn{6}{>{$}l<{$}}{\,\,a+h+q = b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q}\\
      & \multicolumn{5}{>{$}l<{$}}{\quad +r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z}\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i  
\end{tabular} \notag\\
\end{align}
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}r<{$}}
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i &\quad  (2)\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i &  \quad (3)\\
    \multicolumn{6}{>{$}l<{$}}{\,\,a+h+q = b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q}& \\
      & \multicolumn{5}{>{$}l<{$}}{\quad +r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z}  & \quad (4) \\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i  & \quad (5)
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Figure 2]

### Two

I have tried with TikZ and tikzlibrary `fit` and `matrix`:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=.25em, column sep=0em]{%
        \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 &\node[xshift=8.5em]{(6)};\\
        \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(7)};\\
               \,\, a+h+q & &     &\qquad   & &     &\qquad   & &     & \\
                          & &     &\qquad   & &     &\qquad   & &     & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(8)};\\                
        \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(9)};\\
};
\node[yshift=0.95em,fit=(table-3-2)(table-3-3)(table-3-4)(table-3-5)(table-3-6)(table-3-7)(table-3-8)(table-3-9)]{$$=\,\,b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q$$};
\node[yshift=0.95em,xshift=-.9em,fit=(table-4-2)(table-4-3)(table-4-4)(table-4-5)(table-4-6)(table-4-7)(table-4-8)(table-4-9)]{$$+r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z$$};      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

---

Is it possible to do this in math-mode, i.e. is there a suitable environment for doing this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}

\begin{document}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{align}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i\\
    \multicolumn{6}{>{$}l<{$}}{\,\,a+h+q = b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q}\\
      & \multicolumn{5}{>{$}l<{$}}{\quad +r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z}\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i  
\end{tabular} \notag\\
\end{align}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}r<{$}}
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i &\quad  (2)\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i &  \quad (3)\\
    \multicolumn{6}{>{$}l<{$}}{\,\,a+h+q = b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q}& \\
      & \multicolumn{5}{>{$}l<{$}}{\quad +r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z}  & \quad (4)\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a &\,= b+c &\qquad d &\,=e+f &\qquad g &\,=h+i  & \quad (5)
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=.25em, column sep=0em]{%
    \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 &\node[xshift=8.5em]{(6)};\\
    \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(7)};\\
           \,\, a+h+q & &     &\qquad   & &     &\qquad   & &     & \\
                      & &     &\qquad   & &     &\qquad   & &     & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(8)};\\                
    \phantom{a+h+q}a  &=& b+c &\qquad d &=& e+f &\qquad g &=& h+1 & \node[xshift=8.5em]{(9)};\\
    };
    \node[yshift=0.95em,fit=(table-3-2)(table-3-3)(table-3-4)(table-3-5)(table-3-6)(table-3-7)(table-3-8)(table-3-9)]{$$=\,\,b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q$$};
    \node[yshift=0.95em,xshift=-.9em,fit=(table-4-2)(table-4-3)(table-4-4)(table-4-5)(table-4-6)(table-4-7)(table-4-8)(table-4-9)]{$$+r+s+t+u+x+y+w+z$$};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What sort of geometry are you using, since the long equation will not fit into a default \textwidth?

Comment: i'd simply use `\rlap{...}` to make the long right-hand side "invisible" to the alignment.  (you'll still have to break it manually if it's too long, and maybe add a negative vertical adjustment after the `\\ ` ending the first line.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did not understood yuor question, sorry... I'm using standard geometry of `article` class, but this is clear for my MWE and then I think this is not your doubt...

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much! It works with some adjustments :-)

Comment: What's wrong with your current approaches?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems: First, ignoring the long equation while aligning the others.  Second, centering the long equation into the display area.  The first is achieved by `\mathrlap` (from mathtools} and the second by using `flalign` and `\hspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\tempdima}{$\displaystyle a+h+q = b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p$}%
\setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\tempdima}%

\begin{flalign}
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i &\\
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i \\
\hspace{\tempdima}
 a+h+q &= \mathrlap{b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p}\notag\\[-1ex]
       &\quad \mathrlap{{}+u+x+y+w+z}\\
 a &= b+c & d &=e+f & g &=h+i
 \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image: overlapped equations]

Comment: @JohnKormylo Than you very much! I have tried with `\rlap` and `alignat`, but I have had to put some `\qquad` at the end of the first line to avoid 'overfulls'...

Comment: the vertical space between the long line and its continuation should really be tighter than the other between-equation spaces.  it would also be a good idea to make the break sooner, so that the long line doesn't overlap the space "reserved" for the equation numbers.

Comment: @barbara benson - You guys are going to make me work for this one.

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- but the result looks much nicer.  thanks.  (by the way, it's "beeton", not "benson".)